# Tag a video uploaded to Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, video, tagging

I am working on a Facebook app that uploads a video to your Facebook Timeline. I would like to be able to tag the user's friends in the video, since I am processing the video to include their profile pictures. There are never more than 4 friends, and they appear in the video, so that shouldn't be violating any spam rules.

Is there a way to automatically tag the people in this video? I am uploading the the /videos endpoint using Curl in PHP, and getting the video id back as a response, and attempting to POST to /video_id/tags to tag users, but it isn't working. Is there a way to handle this?

Thanks,
Esa

Answer (score 0):

Right, seems it is not possible to tag an uploaded video by POSTing to https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos (either when the video is uploaded with `tags=` or `tags[]=`, or after the video has been uploaded).

As a workaround, you could think about using an Open Graph action and tagging the action.  For example, "Esa uploaded a video" and add tags for Esa's friends.  This would also give you OG Aggregation stories in the user's timeline.

Info on tagging an OG action:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingpeople